# Does this paper show that the cluster of cases around Wuhan Institute of Virology was bigger than the cluster of cases around Huanan Seafood Market?

Tags: covid-19

[In this interim report on covid-19](https://www.help.senate.gov/imo/media/doc/report_an_analysis_of_the_origins_of_covid-19_102722.pdf) released by the United States Senate Committee on Health, Education, Labor and Pensions, figure 5 shows a plot of the social media activity of Weibo users in a covid-19 assistance channel.

> [image]

The senate report never references figure 5, but the report clearly implies that figure 5 shows there were more cases around the Wuhan Institute of Virology than the Huanan Seafood Market. [This youtube video talking about the report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaJt5jC5gbY) with 800k views says that the figure shows that the initial cluster of covid cases were primarily around the WIV.

The figure is taken from [this open access paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/9/6/402). Is it legit or not.

Comment: Note that this map is essentially saying that social media use is higher in the city center then in the suburbs. I will gladly believe that but I don't see what that is supposed to prove about Covid-19.

Answer (score 6):

The map shows ***no cluster of cases around Wuhan Institute of Virology***. It is around a nearby park.

[image]

[image]

The fallacy here is shifting *near* the Institute to *around* the Institute.

However, the report does indirectly reference the map when it points to an infected researcher from Wuhan as a possible source.

> **Basis for Assessment that Research**
>
> ...A research-related incident is consistent with the early epidemiology showing rapid spread of the virus in Wuhan, with ***the
> earliest calls for assistance being located in the near the WIV’s original campus in central Wuhan.*** It also
> explains the low genetic diversity of the earliest known SARS-CoV-2 human infections in Wuhan, because
> the likely index case, would be an infected researcher, is the likely primary source of the virus in Wuhan.